# Ember component - Passing parameters to child components without repetition

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an Ember component for a form submission, and I exposed several different form field types (in this case, `text-field`, `checkbox-field`, and so on), but wanted to hide the implementation details by not exposing the name of the components that implement each field (`simple-form-field`). The problem I have is that the component needs to have some variables passed in, so I'd need to repeat the parameter passing for each form field implemented by the same component. Is there a DRY way to avoid doing this?

Here, you can see `changeset=changeset`, `disabled=disabled`, and `inline=inline` are all repeated.

```
// templates/components/simple-form.hbs
{{#with (hash
  text-field=(component 'form/simple-form-field'
    control='control-text' changeset=changeset disabled=isDisabled inline=inline)
  labeled-field=(component 'form/simple-form-field'
    control='control-labeled' changeset=changeset disabled=isDisabled inline=inline)
  dropdown-field=(component 'form/simple-form-field'
    control='control-dropdown' changeset=changeset disabled=isDisabled inline=inline)
  date-field=(component 'form/simple-form-field'
    control='control-date' changeset=changeset disabled=isDisabled inline=inline)
  daterange-field=(component 'form/simple-form-field'
    control='control-daterange' changeset=changeset disabled=isDisabled inline=inline)
  checkbox-field=(component 'form/simple-form-field'
    control='control-checkbox' changeset=changeset disabled=isDisabled inline=inline)
  submit-button=(component 'form/submit-button' disabled=(or changeset.isInvalid isDisabled)))

  as |formFields|}}



  {{yield formFields}}



{{/with}}
```